# If a pin was bent during CPU installation would the machine have started at all?

Tags: boot, installation, cpu, troubleshooting, pin

Realistically, if a Pin was bent during install would it have turned on and ran for 30 minutes or so before cutting out, or would it just have not started even once?

The machine turned on first time, and happily sat in the BIOS for 20 odd minutes whilst preparing a USB Drive elsewhere to install Windows.

When the installation of Windows 8.1 got to the second step (Copying the files needed, I think) the machine turned off completely.

It attempted to restart but the fans just span for a second, and then the power went out again, the fan started, and stoppped, and continues this way.The same thing happens continuously now when the machine is powered on.

Other troubleshooting steps have been attempted and not resolved the problem (It's not the PSU), we haven't had a chance to remove the components and inspect them yet.

Rather than a discussion on further troubleshooting: Realistically, if a Pin was bent during install would it have been able to turn on and run for 30 minutes or so before cutting out is the question...

Comment: if you bent it and then straightened it then it shouldn't matter that it was bent. It's common for a pin to bend and then you use a credit card and tweezers to straighten it

Comment: but as to the question of what happens if a pin is bent and doesn't make contact.. that may depend on the pin, but i've never tested it and don't know anybody who has, at least not for each individual pin, and even then it may depend on the processor. If you stated what pin it was that might help ppl answer

Comment: I don't know for sure that the pin is bent, so the question is more theoretical at this point. Not had a chance to inspect the CPU and Socket yet, but it got me wondering whether it would boot up and work for a while, then suddenly stop working - Assuming the machine was kept in one position once running

Comment: If all pins were needed all the time, there'd be way less pins as they'd just combine many of them. ;)  Determine which pin it was, look up the pinout for your CPU and determine what that pin is used for. It may be very obvious as to whether it was need for basic booting or not.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It's actually better to transfer power using more smaller pins because you get a slightly larger contact area between pin and socket using five 0.2mm diameter pins than a single 1mm pin. Also due to the [skin effect](http://www.rowand.net/shop/tech/wirecapacitychart.htm): *When electricity flows through a wire, it mostly flows on the surface of the wire, not through the middle. This effect is more pronounced on high frequency AC than it is on DC or low frequency AC. This means that a "wire" of a given size that made up of many smaller strands can carry more power than a solid wire*

Comment: @Mokubai I think you missed my point.  What I was alluding to: Many pins are simply on/off triggers that activate and deactivate parts of the chip. Not all parts will need to be activated at the same time for most tasks. If the CPU worked in a way that they were all activated at once regardless of the task, then they all (or at least, sets of pins) could be triggered with just one pin, reducing the overall number of pins needed, therefore reducing complexity and reducing costs; both of which manufacturers love to do when possible. :)

Comment: For example: You can power a CPU on a workbench using a bench power supply by just attaching the power leads to the CPU's power pins, and then perform basic arithmetic using the chip by just powering/shorting the pins needed, and monitoring the output on other pins.  In that case you'd only be using a small fraction of the CPU (and pins), but it's still working.

Answer (score 0):

To be frank, Yes...However this depends on how bent the pin is..and which pin it is.  If there is any chance at all you can get in there and fix the pin, do it as soon as possible.  Regardless of which pin it is, thermal expansion of the metal in the pin (caused by heat from a cpu, for instance) will cause it to further contort and possibly contact other pins, causing all kinds of havoc.

Comment: I didn't think about the fact that as it heats up the metal in the pin could have expanded and therefore moved, causing it to suddenly stop. I thought it was odd that it could run up at all, but this explanation could be feasible. At the moment it's a theoretical question, I'll inspect the CPU and Socket later to know for sure if a pin has bent.